# JavaFX - How to listen to tab down button when mouse clicked on tabpane?

Tags: javafx-2, actionlistener, tabpanel

[image: Tab Down Button on TabPane]

How can I had an onMouseClicked listener on the Tab Down Button in a TabPane ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can add a MouseEvent handler to the TabPane and find the arrow if clicked there:

```
tabPane.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        EventTarget eventTarget = mouseEvent.getTarget();
        if (eventTarget instanceof StackPane) {
            StackPane stackPane = (StackPane) eventTarget;
            ObservableList<String> styleClasses = stackPane.getStyleClass();
            for (String styleClass : styleClasses) {
                if ("arrow".equals(styleClass) == true) {
                    //TODO
                    System.out.println("arrowEvent");
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```